# Store unserializable objects in flowScope of spring webflow

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Is it possible to configure spring webflow to enable storing unserializable objects in flowScope and in viewScope?
They could be stored in http session without serialization.
Why does webflow do serialization instead of simply storing it in http session?

Comment: Non-serialized object do not fare well in session replicated scenarios like clustered environments.

Comment: That's right, but we may not demand session replication and clustering, sticky session load balancing may be enough, and than storing in http session would be enough - like in many standard web apps.